# How do I include the lwjgl 3.2.2 libraries into intelliJ IDE?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm just starting out with lwjgl and I don't know how to include the libraries into intellij IDE all the other tutorial use older version where the lwjgl folder contains a jar, native and other folders but the new version 3.2.2 contains a whole bunch of lwjgl folders with some random extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create Maven project and add lwjgl dependency from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lwjgl/lwjgl/3.2.2) to pom.xml?

Comment: If you are not using Maven, you can still follow the link from this answer and click on the `jar` label - this will download your desired jar.

Comment: So that's it, this file is like 300KB but the one from the official website is like 75MB.

Comment: Maven is a very powerful tool. One of it's basic funcionalities lets you add dependencies to your projects. It's very useful when you must add external `.jar` to your project. You just have to create Maven project, find a library on e.g. mvnrepository.com, then you copy it's dependency, past it into `pom.xml` (file created automatically when tou create Maven project), and your project will download and add `.jar` automatically. Go watch some tutorials about adding dependencies to Maven, you won't regret.

Answer (score 0):

- go to https://www.lwjgl.org/customize, choose "Stable"
- "Download zip" at the end and extract it
- in your project, CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S, "Modules", then "Dependencies" tab, click on "+"
- add all the jars

You should be good to go

Comment: There's like a million folders in it, are only jars from lwjgl folder are enough?